# How to use scipy to optimize a function

Tags: python, image, optimization, scipy, keras

I'm learning image style migration with scipy and keras. I'm trying to run a sample code but get an error with scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b:

```
x, min_val, info = fmin_l_bfgs_b(evaluator.loss, x.flatten(),fprime=evaluator.grads, maxfun=20, epsilon=1e-7)
```

But I get an error:

```
ValueError: failed to initialize intent(inout) array -- expected elsize=8 but got 4
```

Where evaluator is a object of class Evaluator

```
class Evaluator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.loss_value = None
        self.grad_values = None

    def loss(self, x):
        assert self.loss_value is None
        loss_value, grad_values = evalurateLossAndGrads(x)
        self.loss_value = loss_value
        self.grad_values = grad_values
        return self.loss_value

    def grads(self,x ):
        assert self.loss_value is not None
        grad_values = np.copy(self.grad_values)
        self.loss_value = None
        self.grad_values = None
        return grad_values
```

The method loss returns a scalar while grads returns a vector which length equals to the number of pixels in the image. Name `x` is a image of size 512*512*3.
How can I fix this bug? Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you turn this into a runnable example?

Answer (score 1):

This error is because the fortran implementation of scipy's L-BFGS solver requires 8-byte instead of 4-byte floats. It requires you to cast your initial x and your gradients to `float64` datatype.